# ... API Call oAuth2.0 Refresh Token issue PandaDocs

Tags: php, curl, oauth-2.0, pandadoc

I am having a problem trying to get an ACCESS_TOKEN from the REFRESH_TOKEN provided on PandaDocs API..

What are the correct parameters to send in order to get a new ACCESS_TOKEN from a refresh token?

I stored the refresh token I originally recieved when I first authenticated to upload a doc to be signed. I now want to use the refresh token to get an new access token in order to check the status of the signatures on the doc.

I am trying to get a new access token using the refresh token I stored but I keep getting grant_type is invalid.

This is my code..

```
    $token = '(refreshtokenhere)';
    $url = "https://app.pandadoc.com/oauth2/access_token"; 
  $useragent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.342.3 Safari/533.2';
        $ch = curl_init();
        $headr = array();

        $headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8';


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);

        $postfields['grant_type'] = 'refresh_token';
        $postfields['refresh_token'] = $token;
        $postfields['client_id'] = CLIENT_ID;
        $postfields['client_secret'] = CLIENT_SECRET;


        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );


        echo $ret = curl_exec($ch); //
```

Comment: You haven't mentioned where you are getting this token from or what for

Comment: I have the refresh_token saved from when I first authenticated. I stored it to reuse it..

Comment: Its from PandaDocs...

Comment: OK suggest you add that to your question so people who know the service can help

Answer (score 2):

Check the API documentation. The `grant_type` should contain the authorisation code.

https://developers.pandadoc.com

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

EDIT:

grant_type should be as it is shown in your code ie literal string "refresh_token".

As you spotted remove the content type header so the post fields are sent properly.

Comment: I already tried that , it still gives me

"error_description": "No 'grant_type' included in the request.", "error": "invalid_request"}

Comment: if the authorisation_code was bad wouldnt it state that rather than stating no grant_type is included? The code I am using is the REFRESH_TOKEN that it gave me when i authenticated.  Perhaps there is something else wrong here in my code?

Comment: You said that the error was grant_type is invalid? Are you sending the literal string "refresh_token" or the actual token? If the actual token then I assume the authorisation code is a different thing

Comment: Also why do you need to get a new token? Why not just use the one you already have?

Comment: Because the token eventually times out and I need to peridoically check to see if the edocs were signed. Which may be many hours later or even the following day.  So what I do is store the refresh token in order to access the document when the original access token times out.

Comment: Fair enough sounds sensible.. umm are you sure the refresh token is the same thing as the authorisation code that is referenced in the docs? I am not sure but it doesnt sound like the same thing

Comment: "You said that the error was grant_type is invalid? Are you sending the literal string "refresh_token" or the actual token? If the actual token then I assume the authorisation code is a different thing"

I tried both... When using the AUTH_CODE that is send to me when first authenticating I send the literal string 'authorization_code' and  for code I send the AUTH_CODE ...

This works fine and I get back an access_token and a refresh_token.  I then save the refresh_token to a database for later access

Comment: The problem is that I dont know what exact parameters I need to send so I can get a new ACCESS_TOKEN using the REFRESH_TOKEN provided..

Comment: OK so I guess to get a new authorisation code just repeat the process. Dont bother changing this grant_type value to "refresh_token" just re-use whatever worked before maybe?

Comment: The API Docs doesnt describe how to do this.... Other OAUTH2 websites use the 'refresh_token' as a literal string for grant type...

Comment: Ahh OK I am getting you. Again would have helped us along if the title to your question was "oAuth2.0 Refresh Token issue" or similar. Can you sort the question out as you are showing a different error in the comments

Comment: I can do that but it will require to actually manually click to get authenticated again.. What is the purpose of a refresh token if I have to get authenicated again manually. I would like to use the refresh_token as that is the purpose of it. My application runs in the background to peridocally check every 5 minutes to see if the docs were signed. If I have to manually authenicate every 5 minutes those popups will get really annoying after a while... This is the purpose of the refresh token iso we can avoid this...

Comment: Cool. Your totally right about the grant type it defo should be sent as "refresh_token". Which error are you getting? No grant type or grant type invalid? http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749 section 6

Comment: This is the error right now I was getting Invalid before... I must of made a change somewhere putzing around with the code...

 "No 'grant_type' included in the request.

B

Comment: Do i have to send content size or something else in the headers?

Comment: Nah shouldnt have thought so. As an aside I would use Guzzle or something similar if you can rather than messing around with curl which is always a pain. Are you absolutely sure you have a post field called grant_type being sent? Can you dump the request out before sending it?

Comment: I got it to work!

I removed the following lines:

 $headr[] = 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headr);

and kept everything else the same!

Sweet.....
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ahh no worries - I was going to ask why that was there as didnt see any json in your body. Cool though was a tricky one. I will update my answer with this solution but dont feel obliged to give me any credit as you got it on your own and my answer was total b*lls

Answer (score 1):

In that token field which value you are passing. It should contain refresh token obtained previously, not access token.

Comment: In the comments he is clearly saying he is reusing the refresh token he saved before.